# efficient X within limit algorithm

Tags: performance, math, erlang

I determine limits as `limit(0)=0; limit(y)=2*1.08^(y-1), y∈{1,2,3,...,50}` or if you prefeer iterative functions:

```
limit(0)=0
limit(1)=2
limit(y)=limit(y-1)*1.08, x∈{2,3,4,...,50}
```

Exmples:

```
 limit(1) = 2*1.08^0 = 2
 limit(2) = 2*1.08^1 = 2.16
 limit(3) = 2*1.08^2 = 2.3328
 ...
```

for a given `x∈[0,infinity)` I want an efficient formula to calculate `y` so that `limit(y)>x and limit(y-1)≤x` or 50 if there is none.

Any ideas? 
or is pre-calculating the 50 limits and using a couple of ifs the best solution?

I am using erlang as language, but I think it will not make much of a difference.

Comment: How about just solving `limit(y) > x` analytically for `y` with pen and paper?

Comment: That's what I meant with "pre-calculating the 50 limits and using a couple of ifs"

Comment: @simpleBob: No, you didn't ;) "Solving analytically" is what Amadan does in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
limit(y) = 2 * 1.08^(y-1)
limit(y) > x >= limit(y - 1)
```

Now if I haven't made a mistake,

```
2 * 1.08^(y - 1) > x >= 2 * 1.08^(y - 2)
1.08^(y - 1) > x / 2 >= 1.08^(y - 2)
y - 1 > log[1.08](x / 2) >= y - 2
y + 1 > 2 + ln(x / 2) / ln(1.08) >= y

y <=  2 + ln(x / 2) / ln(1.08) < y + 1
```

Which gives you

```
y = floor(2 + ln(x / 2) / ln(1.08))
```

Comment: the code will surely be nicer than 50 ifs, but the algorithm must be efficient as well. Any idea how efficient 1xln+2xdiv+floor+sum is compared to a maximum of 49 ifs in erlang?

Comment: Only one way to find out, measure. But I would guess that it is more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the approach, but the ifs are still way faster